# Options for configuration of python libraries

Tags: python, configuration, environment-variables

I wrote a library around a REST API that I am going to use in other libraries or python projects. In this library I need some variables like URLs that I didn't want to hardcode into the library, but make it configurable. I don't want the URL or the USER and so on to be in input in the functions of that library, because in that case I would end up with handing them over on and on and need to provide them in every call. So they should be part of the config.

My current solution is that I just wrote `os.getenv("MY_URL")` at the place I needed it and export those variable in the application. That is outlined in solution 1 and it is a solution that works.

I want to understand alternatives and what the proper pythonic way of solving this topic is. My question is not about how to store a config for an application. I know about options to export something to environment and about ways to load TOML, JSON, INI and so on.

### 1. Solution simply using os.environ

I use the environment to hold the config of the library. The library just assumes that the needed environment variables are set. The script or application has the responsibility to export them.

`my_package/__init__.py`

```
from .my_module import my_func
```

`my_package/my_module.py`

```
import os


def my_func():
    print(os.getenv["MY_URL"])
```

A possible usecase could look like this:

`main.py`

```
import os

import my_package


os.environ["MY_URL"] = "http://example.com"

my_package.my_func()
```

Advantages:

1. I don't need to define the variable inside the library or before import.
2. It can be handy when working with docker to put configuration directly into the container environment.
3. I can change the values during runtime by just manipulating the environment.

Possible downsides:

1. Only strings can be used. That doesn't matter for the things I need currently and obviously one can transform the strings again.
2. I don't know whether it is good practice to have a `os.getenv()` just there in the library. It feels a bit hacky.

### 2. Solution using a global variable in the library and monkey patching

I have no clue, whether this is common style at all. Or if it's good design. The idea is I set the variables I need to use to None and do monkey patching in my scripts or applications. To make it convenient I could use a dictionary for that.

`my_package/__init__.py`

```
from .my_module import my_func


config = None
```

`my_package/my_module.py`

```
# other code

def my_func():
    print(my_package.config["MY_URL"])
```

A possible usecase could look like this:

`main.py`

```
import my_package


my_package.config = {"MY_URL": "http://example.com"}

my_package.my_func()
```

Advantages:

1. I don't need to define the variable inside the library or before import.
2. I can change the values during runtime by just monkey patching again.
3. I don't rely on the environment in the library, but still I could search in the environment for the values and add them to the dict.

Possible downsides:

1. That looks more hacky than solution one.

### 3. Solution using a global variable in the library and define a config method to override it.

I have again no clue, whether this is common style at all. Or if it's good design. The idea is I set the config dict to None and call the config method  in my scripts or applications that takes the dict. The benefit would be that I can log the calls to this config method and that looks cleaner. Although it is more effort compared to solution 1.

`my_package/__init__.py`

```
from .my_module import my_func
from .config import config_loader
```

`my_package/config.py`

```
from logging import getLogger


config = None


def config_loader(config_dict):
    global config
    logger.info(f"config loaded: {config_dict}")
    config = config_dict


logger = getLogger(__name__)
```

`my_package/my_module.py`

```
import my_package.config as cfg
# other code

def my_func():
    print(cfg.config["MY_URL"])
```

A possible usecase could look like this:

`main.py`

```
import my_package


my_package.config_loader({"MY_URL": "http://example.com"})

my_package.my_func()
```

Advantages:

1. I don't need to define the variable inside the library or before import.
2. I can change the values during runtime by just calling the method again.
3. I don't rely on the environment in the library, but still I could search in the environment for the values and add them to the dict.
4. I have a defined way to set this config to s

Possible downsides:

1. That's more complicated over all and maybe exotic.

Comment: Have a look at Pydantic https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/settings/. It may help you get some ideas.

Comment: I see how pydantic could help importing config. But I don't see how that help me defining how I connect that config values with my library.